# Getting events type of update on subscription to presence using MS Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

After creating a presence subscription, events are sent to the web hook more often than necessary. When changes happen, events come. But when activity and availability do not change, then events still come when they shouldn't.

And I see that every 1-2 minutes the same activity and availability of the current user comes in, even though it hasn't changed state.`enter code here`

Сreating a subscription

```
{
"inputs": {
    "method": "POST",
    "uri": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions",
    "headers": {
        "Authorization": "Bearer @{body('Анализ_JSON')?['access_token']}"
    },
    "body": {
        "changeType": "updated",
        "notificationUrl": "@{variables('Адрес веб-хука')}",
        "resource": "/communications/presences?$filter=id in (@{body('Преобразование_в_строку_Массива_1')})",
        "expirationDateTime": "@{body('Получение_будущего_времени')}",
        "clientState": "secretClientValue",
        "latestSupportedTlsVersion": "v1_2"
    }
}
```

}

[Example HTTP query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdrU0.png)

Comment: Please share the code of your problem as text and not screenshot so that it can be used or marked in answers.

Comment: It is Power Automate process. I added code of http action.